# Как мне сделать таблицу?

Tags: html, javascript

Как мне сделать таблицу, чтоб она была пустая без ячеек и разделана линией пополам (ну, как бы квадрат должен получиться разделённый линией)? Но чтоб в этой таблице писать можно было.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <table style="border:1px solid #000;border-collapse:collapse">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;"></td>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

создаем таблицу, можно с двумя  можно и с одной а можно и n-количеством.
таблице задаем border, а всем td что находятся сверху задаем border-bottom.